# Can you read connection strings from function bindings?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, azure-functions

**Can we bind to connection string value in order to simply output-bind to a specific storage account?**

I would like to create a blob mover, where the consumer would pass an object like:

```
{
    "sourceConnection":"..blob connection string",
    "destinationConnection":"...blob connection string",
    "filename":"/someContainer/someDir/myfile.jpg"
}
```

The function would be trigger by a queue:

```
    {
        "name": "myQueueItem",
        "queueName": "myqueue-items",
        "connection":"",
        "type": "queueTrigger",
        "direction": "in"
    }
```

...where `myQueueItem` would have the payload as above.

**How do we move a blob from `sourceConnection` to `destinationConnection`?**

I'm specifying both the `javascript` as well as `c#` tags, because I need to make a solution in either one.

If we assumed that the source as well as destination storage accounts were the same, we could simply write a function to move blobs between two containers like so:

```
public static class BlobMover
{
    [StorageAccount("Connection")]
    [FunctionName("BlobMover")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("%BlobMover:TriggerQueue%")] BlobMessage msg,
        [Blob("{source}-error/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] CloudBlockBlob error,
        [Blob("{destination}/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] CloudBlockBlob @out,
        [Blob("{source}/{name}", FileAccess.Read)] CloudBlockBlob @in,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await @out.StartCopyAsync(@in);
    }
}
```

However, the storage accounts are going to be different, so the solution above would not work.

Comment: The goal is to move blobs right ? Anyway you get a payload from consumer ? Can i suggest a solution with httptrigger ?

Comment: No. I need to move a blob between storage accounts. I suppose forcing this to be compatible with bindings is not priority

Answer (score 2):

Let’s assume you receive a payload input using a `HTTP Triggered` Azure function:

```
public class Payload
{
    public string SourceContainer { get; set; }
    public string DestinationContainer { get; set; }
    public string SourceConnection{ get; set; }
    public string DestinationConnection{ get; set; }
}
```

Now receive the information from the request:

```
var payload = req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Payload>();
var sourceConnection = payload.SourceConnection;
var destConnection = payload.DestinationConnection;
var sourceContainer = payload.SourceContainer;
var destContainer= payload.DestinationContainer;
```

Create the `sourceClient` and `destinationClient`:

```
#SOURCE
CloudStorageAccount sourceAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(sourceConnection);
CloudBlobClient sourceClient = sourceAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

#DEST
CloudStorageAccount destAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destConnection);
CloudBlobClient destClient = destAccount .CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

#### Downloading from source

```
CloudBlobContainer sourceBlobContainer = sourceClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainer);
ICloudBlob sourceBlob = await sourceBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync("MyBlob.doc");
await sourceBlob.DownloadToFileAsync("MyFile.doc", FileMode.Create);
```

#### Uploading to the destination

```
CloudBlobContainer destBlobContainer = destClient.GetContainerReference(destContainer);
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("NewBlob.doc");
await destBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("MyFile.doc");
```

Comment: looking for a javascript answer as well